# A good development workflow for static sites with one or two PHP files?

Tags: workflow, server-side, static-site

so I'm still learning a lot about best practices and local development workflows when working on my web projects. At the moment, when I develop a static site locally I tend to use Grunt + Bower + some static site generator to start up a local server really quickly. On the other hand when I'm working on a more PHP focused project I will set up a Vagrant box, depending on the focus. My question though is what is the best way to locally develop static sites that have one or two PHP files within them, such as a handler for a contact form? I can't run the PHP on my local server under grunt (at least as my current workflow stands — I use the browsersync plugin — is there a way to do this?), but using Vagrant seems like overkill, especially sometimes when I've settled into using a static site generator, and later realise I need to write a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nginx](https://nginx.org/) to reverse proxy requests to your localhost (your machine). This would route *.php to other IP (a vagrant machine just for those two PHP that happened later) and all other static request to you local grunt server.

With this setup your development site would ever be in http://localhost/ or http://localhost:xxxx where `xxx` is some port. But, depending on the target requested (php, jpg, html, etc) the request will be routed to right place.